# How can I keep my 9 year old spayed female chihuahua from masturbating?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My 9 year old, spayed female chihuahua continually masturbating against my livingroom carpet and my throw pillows on my sofa. This needs to stop.

Comment: Dogs don't masturbate. Can you explain exactly what she's doing? Is she licking her genital area?

Comment: She may need her anal glands emptying. A vet can show you how to do this.